# CSS/HTML fieldset with legend side by side

Tags: css, html, legend, fieldset

I just wanna ask how can i make that side by side? i know this has already been questioned many times here but i already tried the solutions that they've said worked. like adding `<div>` or putting a class wrap in the `<div>` or using `box-sizing` but neither of them worked.

Any suggestions?

[image: click to see]

EDITED:
here are my codes:

CSS:

```
html, body, h1, form, legend, ol, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: dimgray;
    color: #dimgray;
    font-family: "Gill Sans MT", sans-serif;
    padding: 15px;
}

/*size of the gray box inside legend*/
form#payment {
    background: #696969;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 400px;
}   

/*title in the legend/legend itself*/
form#payment legend {
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/*legend inside the Card details (choosing of card type)*/
form#payment fieldset fieldset legend {
    color: #111111;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

/*gray box inside legend*/
form#payment ol li {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
form#payment ol ol li {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    float: left;
}

/*input details/label*/
form#payment label {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 110px;
}

/*arrangement/organization of card type legend*/
form#payment fieldset fieldset label {
    background:none no-repeat left 50%;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    width: auto;
}


form#payment input:not([type=radio]),
form#payment textarea {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font: "Gill Sans MT", sans-serif;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}

/*radio button position*/
form#payment input[type=radio] {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

form#payment button {
    background: #191970;
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: 18px "Gill Sans MT", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 7px 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="payment">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Delivery address</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label>Address</label>
                <textarea name="address" rows="5" required></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Post code</label>
                <input name="postcode" type="text" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Country</label>
                <input name="country" type="text" required>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
        <legend>Card details</legend>
        <ol>        
            <li>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Card type</legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <input name="cardtype" type="radio">
                            <label for="visa">VISA</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input name="cardtype" type="radio">
                            <label for="mastercard">Mastercard</label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Card number</label>
                <input name="cardnumber" type="number" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Security code</label>
                <input name="secure" type="number" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Name on card</label>
                <input name="namecard" type="text" placeholder="Exact name as on the card" required>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>

    <br>
    <button type="submit">Buy it!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question right, you want the 2 block elements (Delivery address & Card details) to be next each other?
If that is the case, I would recommend using a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation for this.

Then if you include for example Bootstrap Grid, you can use:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        first block goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        second block goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

If this is not what you want, please as already was mentioned, post you code in 
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i can't really use bootstrap or foundation i'm really just a beginner. but here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/aLfh78sn/

Comment: Using a framework like Bootstrap is really made for beginners. 
I would suggest to use Bootstrap and go from there.

Comment: Ok, so i've made a very quick and dirty solution for you. Using the Bootstrap grid (hardcoded) into the CSS. The UI is a bit messed up, cause of your CSS. But atleast you have the result you want/need.

https://jsfiddle.net/aLfh78sn/7/

Comment: that's also my problem. every time i tried the solutions i saw here, i have the result but it is always messed up

Comment: That has to do with your own code messing the UI.
You can't just copy and paste code and cross your fingers that it'll work just fine. You need to learn/understand the code.

So that's why i recommend a framework like Bootstrap, and don't create your own stuff if you don't understand it.